# Fix the first and the second column of dynamic table generated according to JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

Define empty table in HTML file, and append thead and tbody in js file, fill the td content in js file according to data read from JSON file.

Question: How to fix the 1st and 2nd column of this dynamic table?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? What do you mean by "JSON file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just an example. You can try this.

```
var myList = [
    { "name": "abc", "age": 50 },
    { "age": "25", "hobby": "swimming" },
    { "name": "xyz", "hobby": "programming" }
];

function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
            if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $(selector).append(row$);
    }
}

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $(selector).append(headerTr$);
    return columnSet;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable('#excelDataTable')">
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: How to fix the 1st and 2nd column? Other columns can be scrolled(overflow-x: auto;). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Daisy.Hsu If this is helpful for you So please accept my answer.

Comment: @Daisy.Hsu What are the 1st and 2nd column?

Comment: Nope, I want to scroll all content horizontally except the 1st and 2nd column. The 1st column is area name, and the 2nd column is the target value for it, other columns are data day by day.

Comment: Thanks a lot all the same.